# Pandas Dataframe from dict of tuple keys and tuple values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a Python dict like this:

```
{(1,2):(3,4), (4,5):(5,9)}
```

How can I convert it into a Pandas Dataframe like:

| key1 | key2 | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 | 5 | 9 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way using the DataFrame constructor and a MultiIndex:

```
out = (
pd.DataFrame(d.values(), 
              index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d))
  .reset_index()
 )
```

Output:

```
   level_0  level_1  0  1
0        1        2  3  4
1        4        5  5  9
```

If you want to handle custom names automatically:

```
def renamer(name):
    if str(name).startswith('level_'):
        return f'key{int(name[6:])+1}'
    else:
        return f'value{int(name)+1}'

out = (
pd.DataFrame(d.values(), 
              index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d))
  .reset_index()
  .rename(columns=renamer)
 )
```

*NB. This works with any number of keys/values.*

Output:

```
   key1  key2  value1  value2
0     1     2       3       4
1     4     5       5       9
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
(df.swapaxes("index", "columns")
 .reset_index()
 .set_axis(['key1', 'key2', 'value1', 'value2'], axis=1))
```

Or, alternatively,

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
pd.DataFrame(
    np.hstack([np.vstack(df.columns), df.values.T]), 
    columns=['key1', 'key2', 'value1', 'value2'])
```

Output:

```
   key1  key2  value1  value2
0     1     2       3       4
1     4     5       5       9
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new temporary dictionary to split up the tuples?

```
import pandas as pd 
dict_1 = {(1,2):(3,4), (4,5):(5,9)}
dict_2 = {x: [] for x in ['key1', 'key2', 'val1', 'val2']}
for key, val in dict_1.items():
    dict_2['key1'].append(key[0])
    dict_2['key2'].append(key[1])
    dict_2['val1'].append(val[0])
    dict_2['val2'].append(val[1])
    
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_2)
print(df)
```